# Add external library into android studio 0.5.1 project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm using an external library **SVProgressHUD** in my Android studio project as a module. Everything is fine until I upgraded my Android studio to 0.5.1. It always shows the follow error message:

> Error:(7, 17) package org.lcsky does not exist

Here is my settings.gradle:

```
include ':app',':SVProgressHUD'
```

My build.gradle in project folder:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

My build.gradle in SVProgressHUD module:

apply plugin: 'android'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

The build.gradle in my main module:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':SVProgressHUD')
}
```

The gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

Can anybody tell me what could be wrong? Thanks

Comment: I think this probably a bug because I recreated a new project and got the same problem although the dependancy looks correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the build.gradle in SVProgressHUD module:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

Previously it works (before Android 0.5.1) when I set it to:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

Comment: android-library is now deprecated. please use 'com.android.library'
 instead